# MySQL random rows with more often occurrence of rows with higher count?

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have already prepared a MySQL statement that gives me a "friend suggestions". 

The table/result goes like

```
   suggestion_id   |   suggestion_count
```

`suggestion_count` tells how many of "my" friends have the `suggestion_id` in their friends.

In other words it tells how many of "my" friends have this mutual friend.

The goal is to choose a few random rows from this result.

*Please note that the goal is **not** just `ORDER BY RAND()`...*

But this randomness should show more often the `suggestion_id`s with more count,
but not everytime.

The goal is to choose random suggestions but more often those with higher `suggestion_count`.

I am stuck at the `ORDER BY RAND()` part - is RAND() somehow settable for this?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: My bad, I misread your post.. thought you wanted the rand() after getting the higher results... thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell NP :) I'm glad we understand each other now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a weighted random sample.

The `RAND()` function returns a value from 0 to 1. So, you need to generate a random number that's based on the value of suggestion_count.

How about this?

```
ORDER BY (100.0*RAND()) - LEAST(100,suggestion_count)
```

This gives a random number that's smaller the higher your suggestion_count value goes. It's based on a guess that 100 is a large suggestion_count value.

**Edit**

I arbitrarily chose a number of 100 as a "largest" value for suggestion_count. My little formula works like this:

1. For each row in the table it generates a random number in the range 0-100.
2. It then subtracts the value of `suggestion_count` for that row from it. So, if `suggestion_count` is 10 in one row and 20 in another row, the row with the 20 is more likely to come up first than the row with the 10 in the `ORDER BY` operation.
3. But if there was a row with more than 100 in suggestion_count, it would overwhelm the random number and come first every time. So we use that number 100 for all large `suggestion_count` values. That's the purpose of `LEAST()`.

I hope that helps explain my procedure.

**Edit** I used the value `100` because using `MAX(suggestion_count)` is a bit harder to code up and debug. To do that you'll need a more complex query, maybe like this.  *But this isn't going to work directly for you* because I don't know exactly what your tables look like.

```
SELECT a.suggestion_id
  FROM suggestions AS a
  JOIN ( SELECT MAX(suggestion_count) FROM suggestions) AS maxsug) AS b
 ORDER BY (maxsug*RAND()) - LEAST(maxsug,a.suggestion_count)
```

If you used just `MAX()` in your `ORDER BY` clause, you turned your whole query into a single-row aggregate query, because `MAX()` is an aggregate function.

Comment: I've tested it few times and it seems to work, could you please explain the "*It's based on a guess that 100 is a large suggestion_count value*" ? Would it work with the max suggestion_count more than 100?

Comment: Can I replace 100's in `order by` by `MAX(suggestion_count)`? Would it work like dinamicly after that ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `MAX(suggestion_count)`. That will probably work very well. Good idea.

Comment: I tried it and it doesnt seem to work (it started to return only 1 row - always the same one) do you have any idea how to implement MAX() to the query correctly ? :)